# How can I use UTF-8 in SQL Statement?

Tags: c#, t-sql, select, utf-8, persian

I want to read some data from Excel to `DataGridView` C# windows form and I Do this without problem But when I import Large Excel It Take more time and I forced to get 3 or 4 column that I want to Use and import to database.

my code:

```
     public static DataTable ImportExcel(string filePath, string sheetName)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT * FROM [");
            sb.Append(sheetName);
            sb.Append("$]");
            DataAccessLayer myDA = new DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = myDA.OLEDBSelect(sb.ToString(), filePath);
            return dt;
        }
```

my excel file has persian column's Name Like "نام" and "وضعيت پايانه"and "تعداد " and "مبلغ".
How can I use This Column name into Select satement Like This

```
public static DataTable ImportExcel(string filePath, string sheetName)
            {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT نام,وضعیت پایانه,تعداد,مبلغ FROM [");
            sb.Append(sheetName);
            sb.Append("$]");
             DataAccessLayer myDA = new DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = myDA.OLEDBSelect(sb.ToString(), filePath);
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: try this : sb.Append(@"SELECT [نام,وضعیت پایانه,تعداد,مبلغ] FROM [");

Comment: tanks @EagerToLearn .I tried your Code But like this sb.Append(@"SELECT [نام],[وضعیت پایانه],[تعداد],[مبلغ] FROM [");

Comment: Did it work? Sorry I didn't realize they were columns separated by commas :).

Comment: yes . It works successfully

Comment: Great. You mind marking my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add @ before your string to avoid character escape.

```
        sb.Append(@"SELECT نام,وضعیت پایانه,تعداد,مبلغ FROM [");
```

Read more [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hirendra_singh/verbatim-strings-in-C-Sharp-use-of-symbol-in-string-literals/).